# Installing a python + django open source project on my server and making it work?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to install an open source python + django project: http://github.com/coulix/Massive-Coupon---Open-source-groupon-clone

on a server to play with. I'm using mediatemple.net grid-server hosting. I uploaded the files in my html folder but I can't seem to run the program.

I'd love to talk this out with someone and figure it out.

Jordan

Comment: You are probably better off using the Django IRC channel ( *#django on irc.freenode.net* ). This site is not intended for actual talking ;)

Answer (score 3):

Did you check out/follow the directions on [deploying Django](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/)?

Comment: Yes, I already have django installed on my host.

Comment: Did you also set up Apache/whatever server you're using with mod_wsgi (or whatever mod you prefer to use)?